# Are there any publically available recordings of conversations between ATC and pilots?

Tags: air-traffic-control, datasets, flight-tracking

It can be either audio or transcription. 
It would be perfect if it also contains aircraft tracks.

Comment: which country are you asking about?

Comment: You can start with Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=atc+audio

Comment: Are you interested in recordings only or live streaming as well?

Comment: Location doesn't matter. Preferably recorded not live data. Transcribed recordings are the best thing for me. However, most of the transcriptions that I've found are about some incidents but I need something typical.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the recordings/transcriptions? Knowing that might help determine a source, or perhaps alternative way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 18):

LiveATC.net has live and recorded ATC radio for most countries/airports.  There are lots of flight tracking websites, e.g. FlightAware, that have live and recorded radar/ADS-B tracks.  You'll have to correlate the two yourself.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a PPL student and I use two sources:

- **[LiveATC.net](https://www.liveatc.net/)** web site for getting used to live communication on my local airport and also for analyzing recorded communication during my training flights.
- **[VASAviation](https://www.youtube.com/user/victor981994/videos)** YouTube channel, which contains many videos capturing communication during aviation incidents, including charts and subtitles.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: Many publicly available accident/incident reports contain communication transcripts; some of those will contain aircraft tracks, too.